# Insert list of rows

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to a simple insert list of rows from a `DataGridView` to a database.

I have made a `checkedbox` that upon checked, the item will be added to the `DataGridView`.  Now i'm attempting to do the INSERT part.  This what I have come up so far:

```
try
{
    string strAppointment = "SELECT appointmentID FROM APPOINTMENT WHERE appointmentID=@searchappointmentID";
    SqlCommand cmdAppointment = new SqlCommand(strAppointment, connection);
    cmdAppointment.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchappointmentID", txtAppointmentID.Text);

    connection.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataPrescription.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string firstColumn = dataPrescription[0, dataPrescription.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        string strMedications = "SELECT medicationID FROM MEDICATION WHERE medicationName=   ('" + firstColumn + "')";
        SqlCommand cmdMedications = new SqlCommand(strMedications, connection);

        SqlDataReader readMedications = cmdMedications.ExecuteReader();

        if (readMedications.Read())
        {
            string getDrugID = readMedications["medicationID"].ToString();

            string strPrescriptions = "INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION (appointmentID, medicationID, quantity) " +
                "VALUES (@insertAppointment, "
                + getDrugID + ",  "
                + dataPrescription.Rows[i].Cells["columnQuantity"].Value + ");";
            SqlCommand cmdPrescriptions = new SqlCommand(strPrescriptions, connection);

            cmdPrescriptions.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insertAppointment", txtAppointmentID.Text);

            prescriptionsResult = cmdAppointment.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        readMedications.Close();
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Right now it giving me this error: "There is  already an open DataReader associated with the command which must be closed first".  I don't know what I've done wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (initialize the datareader)

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataPrescription.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string firstColumn = dataPrescription[0, dataPrescription.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            string strMedications = "SELECT medicationID FROM MEDICATION WHERE medicationName=   ('" + firstColumn + "')";
            SqlCommand cmdMedications = new SqlCommand(strMedications, connection);
            SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader(); //Insert this line in your code
            SqlDataReader readMedications = cmdMedications.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: So what can you do with the dr then?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to execute a command using a connection that's occupied with the reader, and I would look at that as being the problem. Instead of trying to execute the insert inside the reader, try reading the data to a collection and closing the reader, then iterating the connection to make you're updates.